# ¿Cómo activo mi módulo de Mercado Pago en mi página?

Tags: mercadopago

Me dejó de funcionar el módulo que compre hace unos meses de *Mercado Pago* en mi pagina http://www.daras.com.ar, funcionó durante 5 meses y esta semana dejó de funcionar. ¿Cómo lo podría solucionar?

Comment: Hola Maria, bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te recomiendo que primero pases por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), si tienes dudas puedes pasar por el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Si tienes duda de cómo hacer una pregunta bien recibida por la comunidad puedes ver [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Saludos

Comment: @Maria no me queda claro cuando decís, modulo que compre, MercadoPago no vende modelos, podría ser que usaste uno de un tercero y dejo de darle soporte.